# What inspired the Vermicious Knids?

Tags: inspiration, roald-dahl

The Vermicious Knids are a type of dangerous alien creature in the works of Roald Dahl. They appear as primary antagonists in *Charlie and the Great Glass Elevator* and get passing mentions in other Dahl stories such as *James and the Giant Peach*. They are made of muscle and able to stretch their bodies into any form, such as letters to spell out the word SCRAM.

---

[image: illustration of Vermicious Knids from the book]

---

These creatures were of course invented by Roald Dahl, but **were they inspired by anything else already existing in sci-fi or fantasy literature?** As a related-but-not-exactly-the-same question, what about their name - **was the term "Vermicious Knid" taken from or inspired by anything else**, or just a typical piece of Dahl nonsense word building?

Comment: *Vermicious* is presumably an adjective derived from *vermin*,

Comment: @PeterShor If they can make letter shapes, a sister adjective to *vermicular* and *vermiculous* seems more likely ‘worm-like’ or ‘wormy’. Or perhaps a combination with ‘verminous’ so both wormy and obnoxious.

Comment: "Vermicious is presumably an adjective derived from vermin"  possibly also a portmanteau with vicious.

Comment: ‘Vermicious’ is actually, as it turns out, in the OED as a variant of ‘’Vermiceous’, ‘of or pertaining to worms, wormy’.